# i18n on drop down menu option

Tags: jsp, internationalization, struts, jstl

I am trying to internationalize a jsp page. I'm using the `<fmt:message key="xxx">` tags to retrieve the corresponding text for different languages. In the jsp page there are some drop down menus implemented using the `<s:select>` tag. For example,

```
<s:select name="priorToApplyingInfo.userProfile.user.suffix" list="suffix" />
```

here the options in the drop down menu will be populated from the list suffix which is present in the .properties file. Is there a way i can internationalize these drop down menus ?

i want this to be done without changing the backend stuff like receiving the input selection and all, can i do that ?

Comment: im sorry im using fmt:message key="xx" tag for retrieving text and the following for dropdowns                                         s:select name="priorToApplyingInfo.userProfile.user.suffix"list="suffix"

Comment: possible duplicate of [i18n on dropdown menu using s:select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407063/i18n-on-dropdown-menu-using-sselect)