# i18n on dropdown menu using s:select tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, internationalization, ognl

I have a dropdown menu in my JSP page which is implemented with `<s:select>` tag it is as

```xml
<s:select name="priorToApplyingInfo.userProfile.phoneNumbers[0].type"
 listKey="key" listValue="value" list="phoneTypes" headerKey="0" headerValue=""/>
```

Now the values in the dropdown menu are from the list `phonetypes` which is implemented as a `HashMap` in `.java` file.

```java
phoneTypes = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
phoneTypes.put(new Integer(1), getText("HOME"));
// Phone ContactBook category for the business phone
phoneTypes.put(new Integer(DAOHelperFactory.OWNER_PROFILE_PHONE_CATEGORY), getText("WORK"));
phoneTypes.put(new Integer(3), getText("MOBILE"));
phoneTypes.put(new Integer(DAOHelperFactory.OWNER_PROFILE_FAX_CATEGORY), getText("FAX"));
phoneTypes.put(new Integer(5), getText("OTHER"));

preferredContact = new ArrayList<String>();
preferredContact.add(getText("HOME"));
preferredContact.add(getText("WORK"));
preferredContact.add(getText("MOBILE"));
preferredContact.add(getText("FAX"));
preferredContact.add(getText("EMAIL"));
preferredContact.add(getText("OTHER"));

bestContactTime = new ArrayList<String>();
bestContactTime.add(getText("AFTERNOON"));
bestContactTime.add(getText("EVENING"));
bestContactTime.add(getText("MORNING"));
```

The keys like `home=home`, `work=work`, etc., are in a `.properties` file I am working on internationalizing this page and I'm unable to find a way to get the translations for the
values in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Do you have translated versions of texts?

Comment: yes we have the english text in package.properties and the translated versions in package_es.properties

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: that is what i am unable to figure out the whole page got the translations applied except for the values in the menu. I guess this is because the .class files are generated when we build it on server side and the locale information is pulled at the client side, im not sure though

Comment: Which language is displayed then, or it's in mojibake?

Comment: @user2707760: Have you tried to use `getText` in JSP? Also how do you change locale?

Comment: we tried gettext it did not work. we changed the locale using jstl

Comment: @RomanC it just comes in english

Comment: @user2707760 Then you need to switch it to your locale.

Comment: @user2707760: Show code that you used to change locale.

Comment: @user2707760: To change locale see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15582074/1700321 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12891293/1700321.

Comment: @RomanC  we changed the locale by passing it in url, the locale change works fine as all the other text is being translated

Comment: @user2707760 Still not translated, what a locale is in the action context before you call `getText()`?

Answer (score 1):

To change locale in Struts2 application you need to include `requst_locale` parameter to some link or form.

```
<s:url var="urlen" includeParams="all" value="">
  <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{#urlen}">English</s:a>
```

If you want to change locale from action class use `ActionContext` to set it and also put it in HTTP session.

```
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(locale);
session.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale);
```

---

You can call `getText` method also in JSP in `listValue` attribute of `<s:select>` tag.

```
<s:select name="priorToApplyingInfo.userProfile.phoneNumbers[0].type"
 list="phoneTypes" headerKey="0" headerValue=""
 listKey="key" listValue="%{getText(value)}"/>
```

Comment: i actually have a integer and a string stored for the given key in the hashmap, with your sol it only returns the integerpart how do i return only the string ?

Comment: So is it working? The key is left as it is.

Comment: i appreciate your help but it still returns the text in english but the whole page is in spanish

Comment: @user2707760: Are you sure you have `HOME` key in your properties file? BTW the key is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, this works now with the following,i dont know y its not working if we give the key and value as seperate                              <s:select name="priorToApplyingInfo.userProfile.phoneNumbers[1].type" list="#{'HOME':'%{getText(key)}','WORK':'%{getText(key)}','MOBILE':'%{getText(key)}','OTHER':'%{getText(key)}','FAX':'%{getText(key)}'}" headerKey="0" headerValue="" listKey="key" listValue="%{getText(value)}"/>

Comment: I tested it with sj:select and it does not seem to work :S. I moved to s:select. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

It seams you didn't switch the locale in Struts2 before you are retrieved the messages from the resources.

`getText()` is localized method and if it using the default text provider as a default behavior then it searches for locale specific keys. You could get the current locale used by Struts2 from action context or direct from your `ActionSupport` action (haven't seen that you have an action and it extends it).

Usually switching locale is done via the `i18n` interceptor where you put a parameter into request `request_locale`. But you could switch it by changing locale in the action context (make sure you are running the same thread as current).

---

```
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(new Locale("es"));
```

You should run this code before any `getText()` is executed to get localized messages.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked (like Aleksandr M wrote on last paragraph):

`<s:select listValue="%{getText(value)}" listKey="key" list="phoneTypes></s:select>`

only I created

`phoneTypes = new HashMap<String, String>()
 phoneTypes.put("HOME", "HOME")
 phoneTypes.put("WORK", "WORK") 
 etc..`

In this case keys are left out (you can write anything here) and on page displays (translated) values.
This solution does not work with list, only map.